# Apache TelnetClient send Up and Down arrow keys

Tags: apache, keyboard

I use Apache TelnetClient to send `up` and `down` arrow key events. It has no effect, I use the keyboard ASCII codes 38 and 40. The `Enter` key code 13 is ok.

```java
 public void executeCommand(final byte[] command) throws Exception {
       networkClient.executeCommand(command);
 }
```

[image]

My aim is to select the debug option using the arrow keys, and then send `enter` key.

Comment: please see the image,my purpose is to select debug,and then enter it,in order to select debug menu must be use keyup or keydown,but is doesnot effect